# How can I fix .slideToggle transition or animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used .slideToggle in my hamburger menu it works fine but the animation or transition is kinda just jump here's a link don't know what's the problem. http://markthatred.netau.net/

Comment: you want scrolling effect.?

Comment: your design template still need adjust more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have applied `transition` to all elements in your css which is not good idea and it is conflicting with jQuery `.slideToggle()`.
Either remove it from `*` selector or explicitly make it `none` in `nav` selector.

```
nav {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove this from your css

```
*{-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;}
```